# I have an array of arrays, how can I reference the array to print only the 0 index item?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array set:

```
myArr = [
   [red, 1],
   [blue, 2],
   [yellow, 3],
   [geen, 4]
];
```

Is there an operator/method in which I can return an array of just the 0 index item?
So end result would be:

```
myArr2 = [red, blue, yellow, green]
```

Comment: Do you mean `['red', 1]`, or is `red` a ref to another var/object?

Comment: Same as in [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19590865/218196)

Comment: You have to use `Array.prototype.reduce` for this task. Just do this one liner `myArr2 = myArr.reduce((p,c) => {p.push(c[0]); return p}, []);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Working Example](https://jsbin.com/lohavar/1/edit?js,console) using map:

```
var a  = [
   ["red", 1],
   ["blue", 2],
   ["yellow", 3],
   ["geen", 4]
];

var b = a.map(function(el) {
  return el[0];
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

ES6

```js
var myArr = [
   ['red', 1],
   ['blue', 2],
   ['yellow', 3],
   ['geen', 4]
];

document.write(myArr.map(a => a[0]));
```

ES5

```js
var myArr = [
   ['red', 1],
   ['blue', 2],
   ['yellow', 3],
   ['geen', 4]
];

document.write(myArr.map(function (a) { return a[0]; }));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like that

```
for(var i=0;i<myArr.length;i++){
    myArr2.push(myArr[i][0]);
}
console.log(myArr2); /// prints red, blue, yellow, green
```